# How to find the last day of each quarter in a given date period in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Now I have a dataframe like this:
(Ticker and date are indexes)

```
Ticker  Date        Open    Low High    Close   Adj. Close  Shares Outstanding                              
A       2007-01-25  34.99   34.05      35.48    34.30       NaN
        2007-01-26  34.30   33.46      34.60    34.41       NaN
        ....
        2007-06-27  34.30   34.00      34.40    34.09       NaN
        2007-06-28  33.98   33.68      34.08    33.97       NaN
        2007-07-01  34.08   33.63      34.32    34.01       NaN
B       2007-01-12  34.99   34.05      35.48    34.30       NaN
        ...
        2007-08-27  34.30   33.46      34.60    34.41       NaN
        2007-08-28  34.30   34.00      34.40    34.09       NaN
        2007-09-01  33.98   33.68      34.08    33.97       NaN
        2007-09-02  34.08   33.63      34.32    34.01       NaN
C       2007-03-28  34.99   34.05      35.48    34.30       NaN
        2007-03-29  34.30   33.46      34.60    34.41       NaN
        2007-04-01  34.30   34.00      34.40    34.09       NaN
        2007-04-02  33.98   33.68      34.08    33.97       NaN
        2007-04-03  34.08   33.63      34.32    34.01       NaN
```

For each ticker, there are stock prices for each day for many years. However, I only want the quarter end prices for each company, and get a dataframe of all companies' quarterly ending price. I also want to separate each quarter for all companies into different dataframe.

For example:

```
Ticker  Date        Open    Low High    Close   Adj. Close  Shares Outstanding                              
A       2007-06-30  34.99   34.05      35.48    34.30       NaN
B       2007-06-30  34.30   33.46      34.60    34.41       NaN
        ....
c       2007-06-30  34.30   34.00      34.40    34.09       NaN
```

Once problem is, due to the fact that the stock market won't open on weekend. So the quarter end for each ticker might not be calendar quarter end. For example, Q2 ends on 6/30, but stock quarter end might be on 6/29. Is there a way I can find the last day of the given date range for each quarter?

Answer (score 0):

A simple GroupBy is all you need:

```
quarter = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q', name='Quarter')
result = df.groupby(['Ticker', quarter]).last()
```

To get data for a specific quarter:

```
result.loc[('A', '2019Q1')]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, However, when I use the code, I receive the error "Grouper and axis must be same length". Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would first compute the last row for each ticker in each quarter through `groupby` and `last` into a temporary dataframe, then extract the individual dataframes per quarter from it:

```
tmp = df.groupby(['Ticker', pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q',   name='Quarter')]
```

).last().reset_index(level=0)

```
individual_df = {str(i): df.reset_index(drop=True) for i, df in tmp.groupby(['Quarter'])}
```

With your example data, it gives:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(individual_df)

{'2007Q1':   Ticker       Date   Open  Low High  Close  Adj. Close  Shares Outstanding
0      A 2007-01-26  34.30     33.46  34.60       34.41                 NaN
1      B 2007-01-12  34.99     34.05  35.48       34.30                 NaN
2      C 2007-03-29  34.30     33.46  34.60       34.41                 NaN,
 '2007Q2':   Ticker       Date   Open  Low High  Close  Adj. Close  Shares Outstanding
0      A 2007-06-28  33.98     33.68  34.08       33.97                 NaN
1      C 2007-04-03  34.08     33.63  34.32       34.01                 NaN,
 '2007Q3':   Ticker       Date   Open  Low High  Close  Adj. Close  Shares Outstanding
0      A 2007-07-01  34.08     33.63  34.32       34.01                 NaN
1      B 2007-09-02  34.08     33.63  34.32       34.01                 NaN}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering, However, when I use the code, I receive the error "Grouper and axis must be same length". Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @KristineLian: what is the index on your dataframe?

Comment: My indexes are both 'Ticker' and 'Date'

Comment: Oh I got it after resetting the index for the original dataframe. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KristineLian: I was about to post a new comment  for that. Nice that you found it by yourself :-).